# Materialize CSS Datepicker is not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, datepicker, materialize

Every Javascript's Materialize CSS Componenet is working fine except my datepicker, it does not show datepicker properly, different with the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html). Here is my datepicker :
[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Inspect the links in your developer tools. I imagine you have conflicting CSS that’s making the link text white.

Comment: absolutely true, thank you.